# Laravel - Throw $exception is not being caught by handler

Tags: php, laravel, exception

In my Laravel 5.6 application, using `throw $e` seems to output the exception direct to screen and bypasses the Handler.php the exception handler. This means in development the exception is not shown by whoops and in production the exception is not reported.

As I write this, I realise I may have been using try/catches incorrectly but maybe someone can confirm this?

My current code:

```
    try{
        $stockLocation = StockLocation::findOrFail($request->location_id);
    } catch (\Exception $e){
        if($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException){
            throw new UserNotifyException('This stock location could not be found on the system', 404);
        }
        throw $e;
    }
```

My intention here was to re-throw any exception that is not a "model not found" and I expected it to be handled in exactly the same way as if the try catch was not there at all?

I now realise I should have probably written the above as:

```
    try{
        $stockLocation = StockLocation::findOrFail($request->location_id);
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e){
          throw new UserNotifyException('This stock location could not be found on the system', 404);
    }
```

Additional to this, is there a better way to handle exceptions that I do not which to be logged? Currently I transform the exception into my own custom exception class (UserNotifyException) and then in Handler.php I ensure this is not reported.

Comment: `is there a better way to handle exceptions that I do not` yes, but I haven't finished writing it [Yet (github)](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Shutdown/blob/master/src/evo/shutdown/Shutdown.php), it's not for Larval specifically, just for PHP in general.  I should mention on PHP7 use `Throwable` not `Exception` when trying to catch all errors.

Comment: If you don't want to click my github link, you can use a combination of `register_shutdown_function`, `set_error_handler` and `set_exception_handler` to catch everything.  But it's somewhat less then trivial to do them all in an extensible way.

Comment: For example with `set_exception_handler` any exceptions not caught go to this call back.  Which then you can do what you like with them.  Another example is `register_shutdown_function` can catch max memory errors (when PHP runs out of ram) something there is no other way to catch (that lets you still run code).  And `set_error_handler` allows you to catch everything else that is not a Throwable, which you can then throw as an actual exception if you like.  As you can tell It's something I have given a lot of thought and time to...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - thanks. Laravel does actually catch exceptions as standard. However, it does not seem to behave in the same way when catching and then re-throwing using `throw $e;`. Im not sure if you have any thoughts on why `throw $e` could product a different result to `throw new Exception('...')` where $e is a previously caught exception?